# Ways of defining a recursive function that counts right-parentheses in a string

Tags: functions, recursion

I'm trying to find a more elegant way of defining a recursive function on $\{(,)\}$ that counts right-parentheses in a string.

Let $r$ be a function on $\{(,)\}$ defined recursively, such that:

- $r(\lambda) = 0$, and
- $r(sx) = r(s) + 1$, if x is symbol )
- $r(sx) = r(s)$, if x is symbol (

I have also found another way of saying the same thing:

Leg r be a function  $\{(,)\}$ defined recursively, such that:

- $r(\lambda) = 0$, $r\left(\mathbf(\right) = 0$, $r\left(\mathbf)\right) = 1$, and
- $r(sx) = r(s) + r(x)$, where x is a symbol

Is the last example correct? Is there anybody who can recommend a better way of defining this?

Comment: To me, both definitions are equivalent. But I find the first definition more immediate, and it's also recursive. I can't see a point in using the second definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two definitions are equivalent.  I agree with the commenter that the first form is more intuitive.

The only change I could suggest would be a typesetting/presentation change to the following:

> Define $r(s)$ recursively by $r(\lambda) = 0$, and $$r(sx) = 
> \begin{cases}
> r(s) +1 & \text{if } x=\mathbf{)}\\
> r(s) & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$
>   (where $x$ is a character/symbol)

By using "otherwise" instead of "if $x=\mathbf($", it is abundantly clear that $\mathbf{)}$ is the only character we care about.  This also extends the definition to work for larger alphabets than $\{(, )\}$.